# use a batch script to run an R script interactively in the R shell

Tags: r, shell, session, batch-file, interactive-mode

I can run an R script non-interactively from a batch file and save the output.

I can open an interactive R session using a batch file.

I can open R AND run a script from a batch file by doing one, then the other (but then the variables from the script are not available in the interactive session).

**What I have not been able to do is to use a batch file to open an interactive R session and run a script from within that interactive session. How can I do this?**

Regarding workarounds:

The purpose is to use the script to load and process a very large dataset daily, and then have that available for use during an interactive session in R, so using a non-interactive session is not an option for this task. Likewise I am aware that I can run an interactive session using the Windows command prompt but for a variety of reasons I do not want to do that. I want everything loaded into the R shell for use there. I realize Task Scheduler would be useful for this, but unfortunately, I do not have permissions to modify Task Scheduler. I am only allowed to use a batch file which is scheduled then by IT.

I apologize if I simply lack the vocabulary to search for the answer to my question effectively and welcome answers directing me to previous questions.

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried that, and I have also tried running a .bat script that starts R with Rgui.exe. I have tried a number of different commands all of which will either start R or run a script, each with different limitations and advantages:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a Rprofile.site script that sources the setup file that loads the data.  Then, from your batch script set the R_PROFILE variable for this session to point to this Rprofile.site script.

In your batch script,

```
@echo off
set R_PROFILE=C:\path\to\Rprofile.site
Rterm.exe
```

In Rprofile.site

```
.First <- function() {
    print("Loading some stuff")
    source("setup.R")
}
```

In setup.R

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10)
```

I guess you could do with the setup.R file and put it all in the `.First` function as well.

Comment: It took me awhile as I don't have permissions for some of these folders, but this worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough rep for it to show up.